# Combining functions based on changing ID Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay, so currently the functions that I have below are working like they are supposed to, but I am going to have over 30+ questions so I am looking for some type of way to cycle through the IDs or questions.

The only changing factor within each function is the ID.

```
// Q1
  $('#pq1').click(function() {
    $("#pq1 span.answer").toggleClass("short-answer");        
    $("#pq1 .expand-btn").text(($("#pq1 .expand-btn").text() == 'Read More') ? 'Read Less' : 'Read More').fadeIn();
  })

// Q2
  $('#pq2').click(function() {
    $("#pq2 span.answer").toggleClass("short-answer");
    $("#pq2 .expand-btn").text(($("#pq2 .expand-btn").text() == 'Read More') ? 'Read Less' : 'Read More').fadeIn();
  })

// Q3
  $('#pq3').click(function() {
    $("#pq3 span.answer").toggleClass("short-answer");
    $("#pq3 .expand-btn").text(($("#pq3 .expand-btn").text() == 'Read More') ? 'Read Less' : 'Read More').fadeIn();
  })
```

Any ideas on how to combine the functions so that I do not need 30+ would be helpful! Thanks.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/7xb59a01/3/

Comment: you can use `class` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use class:

```
$('.pq').click(function() {
    var $pq = $(this);
    $pq.find("span.answer").toggleClass("short-answer");        
    $pq.find(".expand-btn").text(($pq.find(".expand-btn").text() == 'Read More') ? 'Read Less' : 'Read More').fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: This will work for the opening/closing aspect that I am trying to achieve. But, the text for the Read More / Read Less will not change.

I added a fiddle above in my original post

Comment: Did you try changing id's byt the class? ( it works ) https://jsfiddle.net/7xb59a01/1/ with as many question as you want https://jsfiddle.net/7xb59a01/2/

Comment: Ah, that works. I was just adding the class next to the IDs.